# How can I get the value of a React prop in Jest unit tests?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a component like this:

```
export const TransactionReason = ({
  changeReason,
  reason
}) => {
  const handleNext = () => {
    if (!reason)
    changeReason({
      value: defaultReason
    });
  }

return (
     <View>
        <Picker
          testID='reasonPicker'
          selectedValue={reason?.code}
          onValueChange={(value) => changeReason({
            code: value,
            value: value
          })}
        >
      <Button
        testID='reasonButton'
        onPress={handleNext}
      />
    </View>
);
```

I have an action called `changeReason` in the code that I'm testing. That action changes the value of the prop called `reason`. So, in my test, I'm firing the action with:

```
const changeReason = jest.fn();

const rendered = render(
  <TransactionReason
    changeReason={changeReason}
    reason={null}
  />
);

const reasonNext = rendered.getByTestId('reasonButton');
fireEvent.press(reasonNext);

// the action changeReason has been called

// expect(rendered.props) ?
```

So here I wanted to check the new value of `reason`.

In other test, I have been testing props with:

```
expect(Picker.props.someProp).toEqual('Desired value);
```

But in those cases, that `someProp` is explicit in the component:

```
<Picker someProp={'a value'}  />
```

Here I got and undefined when I try to access to:

```
expect(rendered.props.reason).toEqual('Desired value);
```

Any hint please?

Comment: Please give a [mre], `TransactionReason` doesn't seem to use the `changeReason` prop and it's not clear what you're passing in for the test. Maybe pass in a `jest.fn()` and see if it gets called with `{value: defaultReason}`?

Comment: In the 5th line of the example component it's being used `changeReason` that prop is an action, a function. For the test I only want to pass `reason` value as `null`. In `handleNext` will be called the action/function that will change the value

Comment: But it's not actually destructured out of the props, so you have an error. That's why I'm asking for an actual [mre], because I don't know what else you've posted isn't representative.

Comment: @jonrsharpe edited question

Comment: In the test it **doesn't** update the prop. `changeReason` may have been called, but it's just a test double, it doesn't *do* anything. It's not `TransactionReason`'s responsibility what happens after that anyway, just to invoke the callback, so test *that*. (In general it's not a component's responsibility what props it gets passed, so directly testing those values is rarely valuable.)